# Avoid inheriting fields to clones

Tags: content-management, item-clones

Sitecore clones never inherit the values of the `Updated, Updated by, Revision, Created, Created by, Source, Workflow, Workflow State and Lock fields`. That makes perfect sense.

There is also a setting `ItemCloning.NonInheritedFields` that seems to list a set of additional field names or ids that shouldn't be inherited. `Never publish, PublishDate, UnpublishDate and Final Renderings` are good contenders for this field.

Now, this seems to be working fine when performing a clone of an item. But as far as I can see, this doesn't work together with field reset. If I reset a field value of a cloned item, that is in the the `NonInheritedFields` list, or one of the pre-defined fields, it inherits the value from the source item anyway.

Is this really the expected behavior?